# Angular unit testing form

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-unit-test

I am trying to unit test a Login Form, but I am not able to execute it as expected.

TestBed configuration:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [AuthComponent],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

```
it('form should be invalid', () => {
    component.authForm.controls['email'].markAsTouched();

    expect(component.authForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
});
```

When the above test executes I am getting the following error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'markAsTouched')`.

When modifying the test with `fakeAsync` and `whenstable` like this

```
it('form should be invalid', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      component.authForm.controls['email'].markAsTouched();
      expect(component.authForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }));
```

The test result shows as `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS form should be invalid`.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated spec function is mixing real asynchronous code (*fixture.whenStable()*) with the fake async test zone by using *fakeAsync()*.  You have to pick one.  The reason why you are getting that new error is because the function execution is over before the *whenStable()* promise resolves.

Once you fix your inconsistency, they should work about the same way, waiting for all pending tasks in the macro-task queue like *setTimeout()* to resolve.

### "Real" Async

```js
it('form should be invalid', async (() => {
  await fixture.whenStable(); // wait until all pending macro tasks are resolves
  component.authForm.controls['email'].markAsTouched();
  expect(component.authForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

### Fake Async Zone

```js
it('form should be invalid', fakeAsync(() => {
  flush(); // invoke all remaining pending macro tasks.
  component.authForm.controls['email'].markAsTouched();
  expect(component.authForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

For the life of me I don't know which is better.  Also I don't know if this will fix your original problem, since you didn't provide the component code.